# Is Unity Built-in Render Pipeline the default option, which includes mobile/diffuse shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

I have been using mobile/diffuse shader in my project for awhile. However, I am not yet familiar with the term "**Built-in Render Pipeline**".

Is it true that "**Built-in Render Pipeline**" is the default option in Unity, and it also includes **mobile/diffuse** shader along with other default shaders such as standard, sprite, etc... ?

I know that URP and HDRP do not include mobile shaders.

Comment: Those "Mobile" shaders are quite old by now. The graphical capabilities of phones increased a lot since then. So just because you are primarily targeting mobile games doesn't mean you ***must*** use the mobile shaders. In fact, current versions of the Unity manual moved the docs for the mobile shaders to the "Legacy Shaders" section. The current recommended standard for developing for mobile is - as DMGregory's answer says - the Universal Render Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Built-In Render Pipeline is the one you get by default in Unity if you don't start with the URP or HDRP project templates, or deliberately instal the scriptable render pipeline package.

While URP does not have default shaders called "mobile", the whole pipeline together with its default shaders is designed to be "universal" — i.e. working well on a range of platforms, including mobile.

Comment: Would you please tell me if "**Standard Render Pipeline**" (SRP) is another name for "Built-in Render Pipeline" ?  Or are these 2 different from each other ?

Comment: Standard render pipeline is not an official Unity term. SRP stands for Scriptable Render Pipeline — the foundation that both URP and HDRP build on.